# Stop & reenable hover with click

Tags: javascript, jquery, bind

I have a container that fades on a timer when hovered on (`#module-container`) but when clicking on a `.return-news`, it stops the hover and keeps it from fading. Now I need it where, when called through a function, I need to allow the hover effect again on the `#module-container` just like before. Here's the hover code:

```
var module = $('#module-container');
$('.menu-control').add(module).mouseenter(function() {
    module.stop().show();
    clearTimeout(window.mtimer);
        console.log('hovered');
});

$('.menu-control').add(module).mouseleave(function() {
    var time = 3000;
    window.mtimer = setTimeout(function() {
        module.fadeOut(600);
    }, time);
    console.log(window.mtimer);
});
```

By clicking `.return-news`, I've successfully stopping the hover with this line:

```
$('.return-news').on('click',function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    module.add('.menu-control').off('mouseenter').off('mouseleave');
    console.log('stop it!');
});
```

NOT WORKING: If I click `.next-video` then I need to re-enable the hover (which will then use the mouseeneter and mouseleave functions previously declared). I've tried calling this line but it doesn't work:

```
$('.next-video').on('click',function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    module.add('.menu-control').on('mouseenter').on('mouseleave');
});
```

Later, I'll be having the hover re-enabled by calling it using Vimeo's API (instead of the `.next-video` click) but for the sake of time, I stripped the code to it's basic functionality.

[HERE'S THE CODE ON JSFIDDLE.](http://jsfiddle.net/mikemiketm09/cAt47/3/)

Comment: I'm not sure what your end product is supposed to look like or do! WHat do you need to hover and when? And when should the hover go away?

Comment: @DevlshOne - Sorry for the confusion. The reason why it seems odd is because I stripped my request to bare functionality where I'm having the problem. I've updated my question. Please let me know if I need to explain further. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You just make a class "selected" styled the same as :hover, and after you click, toggle the "selected" class. It will look like the hover is frozen there.